# Integral with variable bound of integration

Tags: calculus

Does the following integral $$\int^x_0f(x)dx$$ has some meaning or not? And if yes what is the meaning

Answer (score 2):

In your notation, the symbol $x$ is referenced as a limit and the [dummy variable of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Terminology_and_notation). This is generally regarded as bad form because the symbol $x$ has two entirely different meanings in the same expression. It is better to change the dummy variable of integration  and write

$$\int^x_0f(x')dx'$$

or

$$\int^x_0f(t)dt$$

so it is clear that the dummy variable of integration is different than the variable referenced by the integration limit.

Answer (score 0):

Rigorously, It does not make sense the way it is written because you are treating $x$ both as a fixed element and as integration variable. If, instead, you have $\int_{0}^{x}f(x')dx'$ then its meaning is just the area enclosed between the graph of $f$ and the $Ox$ axis and between $0$ and a given (fixed) $x$ (assuming the integral exists and so on).

Comment: But in many books Integrals like $\int^{x^2}_0sin{\sqrtx}dx$ are written

Comment: Yes, this is true. But this is some sort of abuse of language. We often write integrals as you did in your post because it is simpler. That's why I said **rigorously** it is not correct, but we are often informal. The meaning, however, becomes clearer if you wirte in the rigorous way.