# Why is another variable than "x" , namely, variable " t" , substituted for x in the expression " integral from a to x of f(t)dt"?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, definition

The documents I have consulted quickly pass on the question of knowing why an indefinite integral of a function *f* is not written as " integral from *a* to *x* of *f(x)dx*" but rather as " integral from *a* to *x* of *f(t)dt*".

What confusion or non-sense would it produce to let the variable *x* remain in the expression?

Why is this variable change necessary in the case of definite integral, and not in the case of indefinite integral?

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481843/integral-with-variable-bound-of-integration/3481851#3481851

Comment: @Willy K. Thanks for the link.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533541/1508) is another question that might help to clear things up. Not an exact duplicate, but close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a variable is supposed yo have *one* specific meaning in an equation (or a collection of them that forms some closed whole). The $t$ as variable over which you integrate is one meaning (it takes the values between the limits, if you recall what integration means), the limit is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In definite integration, the variable of integration is basically a dummy variable used for comprehensional purposes. To put that into context, suppose we had:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx$$
If we then performed a substitution, say $e^x$, then using the variable $x$ again would be confusing. It just wouldn't make sense to have $x=e^x$. In fact, this specific case would make the expression impossible to solve! Rather, we could use another variable, like $t$. Setting $t=e^x$ makes so much more sense.